# How can I lock my screen without turning off the monitor? (Xubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, light-locker

- Xubuntu 14.04

When locking my screen, my monitor/screen turns off immediately.

I don't want that to happen immediately, I'd like to have period of about 20-60 minutes or so between the two things. Is that possible?

Whatever I set the first two sliders to, invoking `xflock4` via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> always switches my monitor off:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer to the question above, but a solution to mitigate the problem of turning off the monitor:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge light-locker && sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to disable Light locker, (do this first) then remove light locker

```
sudo apt-get remove light-locker
```

and then install gnome-saver

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Comment: Please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/588393/revisions) If something needs to be done first, put it first in your instructions, and make it complete!  (so please [Edit] your answer and complete using my example edit)  then drop me a note @Fabby